# Is there possibility to Spring Config Server gets config from itself?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Is there possibility or workaround to tell Spring Config Server to get config from itself? I have some common configs for all Spring Boot apps depending on profile and I want config server has possibility to access them without copy-paste.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_embedding_the_config_server):

> An optional property that can be useful in this case is `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap` which is a flag to indicate that the server should configure itself from its own remote repository.

So setting `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true`.